# Hibernate query cache size and expiration configurable?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

In a web application i have configured in Hibernate 4.1.4 both query and second level cache:

```
<!-- Cache -->
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">resources/ehcache.xml</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

Everything is working fine. In the file ehcache.xml i'm able to configure the size and allocation of the second level cache:

```
<ehcache>
 <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
 <defaultCache
 maxElementsInMemory="30000"
 eternal="false"
 timeToIdleSeconds="600"
 timeToLiveSeconds="600"
 overflowToDisk="false"
 maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
 diskPersistent="false"
 diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

But what about the query cache? How many different queries are stored? How long before expire?

I'm tunning this, and want to synchronize second level cache and query cache expiration, but how?
Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the name of the query cache is `org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache`.

So you can add an entry like this:

```
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    ...
    timeToIdleSeconds=...        
    timeToLiveSeconds=...>
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

Comment: Worked! Using Hibernate 4.1.4 and ehcache 2.6.5 the classes that need to be referenced from ehacache.xml are org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache and org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache